# R cleaning messy data: variable value as header in table

Tags: r

I am confronted with messy data. A particular point where I'm stuck is that some values are hidden inside some variables, subsetting the table as some kind of "header".

An example:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = c("header1", "value", "value", "header2", "value", "value"),
    b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    )
```

What I roughly want:

```
df_goal <- data.frame(
    a = c("header1", "value", "value", "header2", "value", "value"),
    b = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    c = c("header1", "header1", "header1", "header2", "header2", "header2")
)
```

So it's basically about manipulating data based on the position of the "headers".

## Edit

Answers so far revolve around the "headers" following some pattern, e.g. "header1", etc. In this case, they work great.

I would, however like to come up with a more general solution where "headers" are arbitrary, e.g. "fererfw" and "ewetwet" instead of "header1" and "header2" in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it with `zoo::na.locf`:

```
df$c <- zoo::na.locf(ifelse(grepl('(header\\d+)', df$a), df$a, NA))
```

**Output:**

```
> df
        a b       c
1 header1 1 header1
2   value 2 header1
3   value 3 header1
4 header2 4 header2
5   value 5 header2
6   value 6 header2
>
```

#### Edit:

With your edit, of arbitrary headers, try:

```
df$c <- zoo::na.locf(ifelse(grepl('(\\w+\\d+)', df$a), df$a, NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(x = cumsum(str_detect(a,'header'))) %>% group_by(x) %>% 
     mutate(c = str_c('header',x)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-x)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  a           b c      
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  
1 header1     1 header1
2 value       2 header1
3 value       3 header1
4 header2     4 header2
5 value       5 header2
6 value       6 header2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the headers are arbitrary without any pattern in them then you can create a vector of known headers, replace the remaining values with `NA` and use `tidyr::fill`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

headers <- c('header1', 'header2')

df %>%
  mutate(c = replace(a, !a %in% headers, NA)) %>%
  fill(c)

#        a b       c
#1 header1 1 header1
#2   value 2 header1
#3   value 3 header1
#4 header2 4 header2
#5   value 5 header2
#6   value 6 header2
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but here is a dependency-free solution:

```
df$c <- 
  rep(
    grep('^header', df$a, value = TRUE), 
    rle(cumsum(grepl('^header', df$a)))$lengths
  )

#         a b       c
# 1 header1 1 header1
# 2   value 2 header1
# 3   value 3 header1
# 4 header2 4 header2
# 5   value 5 header2
# 6   value 6 header2
```